# Representation of $\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx$ as series of power x.

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

I was requested to determine the power representation $$\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx$$ in powers of $x$. My approach was rather simple.

$i)$ Let $f(x)=\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\ln(1-x)$. It is not hard to show that

$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$

and therefore

$$\frac{1}{x}\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}$$

$ii$) We now have $$\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=\int-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n^2}+C$$

$iii)$ ...

All there's left to do is to find the value of $C$ (point $iii$), which is where I struggled, for I can not let $x=0$ nor $x=1$ (results in undefind expression on the integral), and other values of $x$ have not prove to be useful to me. Is my procedure correct and, if so, how can I find the value of $C$?

Comment: This is an indefinite integral, so shouldn't there be a constant $C$?

Comment: Why can't $C$ be an arbitrary constant?  It is an indefinite integral.

Comment: In my calculus text-book, by Stewart, on each example he finds the value of $C$ by giving $x$ and arbitrary value and solving the equation for $C$. I found it strange too, because he never explains why $C$ can't be any arbitrary constant.